# Laravel eloquent, get latest record and perform criterias on it

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Currently having this:

```
$this->foo()
     ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
     ->limit(1)
     ->exists();
```

But this is not exactly what I need. I need the LATEST record, and then check if that record matches the date criteria.

This query will get the latest record, where the date criteria matches.

How do you do this?

Comment: Just to be clear: You need the latest record and then check the date criteria or you need the latest record that matches the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```php
$record = $this->foo()->latest('id')->first();

if($record->created_at <= Carbon::now()->subDays(7)) {
   echo $record->id . ' is recent'
}
```